# Pass variable between steps in Spring Batch using @Configuration class

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-batch

I'm trying to pass a file path string between 2 steps and here's my attempt.

```
  @Bean
  public Step step1() {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
            .<History, History>chunk(1000)
            .reader(step1Reader)
            .writer(step1Writer)
            .listener(new LoggingStepExecutionListener())
            .build();
  }

  @Bean
  public Step step2() {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("step2")
            .<History, ItemRequestModel>chunk(1)
            .reader(new step2Reader<>())
            .processor(step2Processor)
            .writer(step2Writer)
            .listener(new LoggingStepExecutionListener())
            .build();
  }
```

Here's the config class

```
@Configuration
@Component
public class HistConfig {

  private String csvFilePath;

  public String getCsvFilePath() {
    return csvFilePath;
  }

  public void setCsvFilePath(String csvFilePath) {
    this.csvFilePath = csvFilePath;
  }
}
```

and Step1Writer

```
      @Slf4j
      @Component
      public class Step1Writer implements ItemWriter<History>{

      @Autowired
      private HistConfig config;

      @BeforeStep
      public void beforeStepForWriter(StepExecution stepExecution) throws Exception {
        fileName = "abcdefg";
        File file = new File(fileName + EXTENTION);
        writeCsvHeader();
        config.setCsvFilePath(file.getAbsolutePath());
      }

    }
```

and Step2Reader

```
@Slf4j
public class Step2Reader<T> extends FlatFileItemReader<T> {

  @Autowired
  private HistConfig config;

  @BeforeStep
  public void beforeStepForReader(StepExecution stepExecution) {
    DefaultLineMapper<History> lineMapper = new DefaultLineMapper<>();
    DelimitedLineTokenizer lineTokenizer = new DelimitedLineTokenizer();
    lineTokenizer.setNames("id", "date", "category");
    lineTokenizer.setDelimiter(",");
    lineMapper.setLineTokenizer(lineTokenizer);
    lineMapper.setFieldSetMapper(new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<History>() {{
      setTargetType(History.class);
    }});
    setLinesToSkip(1);
    setLineMapper((LineMapper<T>) lineMapper);
    setResource(new FileSystemResource(config.getCsvFilePath()));
  }
}
```

somehow the NullPointerException occurs in Step2Reader's

```
setResource(new FileSystemResource(config.getCsvFilePath()));
```

I've been working on this for hours but things are not working.
Are there any ways I can pass the csvFilePath between steps by only modifying the code but not changing the approach?

I only posted the related code and modified the code to hide some confidential information, apologize in advance if anything looks weird.

Comment: what is 'conf' ,

Comment: @Stultuske just to get a variable from the .properties file. I'll delete that part..

Answer (score 1):

To enable auto-wiring in the class `Step2Reader` please add the `@Component` annotation to it. The same way you did it already in `Step1Writer`.